# How can I import output from a command as a command in Bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

**System**

```
Linux hosek 4.15.0-48-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 3 08:28:49 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Issue**

I need to get output as commands, in a bash script, for storing variables.

**Example**

```
sed -n '/# Main configuration./,/# Websites./p' webcheck-$category.cfg | sed '1,1d' | sed '$ d'
```

This command returns these lines:

```
email_sender='some@email.com'
email_recipients='another@email.com'
```

How can I read/run these output/lines as commands in script? Is storing this output to the file and then read it by `source` command only way?

I tried `| source` at the end of the command, but it reads only from files.

I tried `echo` at the beginning, but that had no effect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [pLumo showed you](https://askubuntu.com/a/1173689/85695), you can indeed `source` them. However, I would recommend against this. If you have something like this:

```
source <(sed -n '/# Main configuration./,/# Websites./p' webcheck-$category.cfg | sed '1,1d' | sed '$ d')

echo "$email_sender"
```

Then, a year later when you come back and look at this script, you will have no idea where this `email_sender` variable is coming from. I suggest you instead change the command and use one that returns only the variable's value and not its name. That way, you can easily keep track of where each variable comes from:

```
email_sender=$(grep -oP 'email_sender=\K.*' webcheck-$category.cfg)
email_recipients=$(grep -oP 'email_recipients=\K.*' webcheck-$category.cfg)
```

Comment: I agree this is better ;-) At least for scripts you intend to use later.

Comment: Thanks to both! Nice and simple. ;)

Comment: For two this is OK, for more I use for loops with an indirection: `for var in email_sender email_recipient email_subject email_attachement etc ; do printf -v "${var}" '%s' "$(grep -oP $var'=\K.*' webcheck-$category.cfg)"; done` However this fails the "simple" criteria.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_06):

```
source <(sed -n '/# Main configuration./,/# Websites./p' webcheck-$category.cfg | sed '1,1d' | sed '$ d')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A data
while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
    data[$key]=${value//\'/}
done < <(grep -E '^([^#].+=.*)' webcheck-$category.cfg)
```

or

```
done < <(sed -n '/# Main configuration./,/# Websites./{//!p}' webcheck-$category.cfg)
```

```
# associative array.
echo ${data[email_sender]}
echo ${data[email_recipients]}
```

### Output:

some@email.com
another@email.com

Answer (score -1):

bash read builtin handles things like this nicely.

```
read -d '' -r email_sender email_recipients < <(
  grep -oP 'email_sender=\K.*' webcheck-$category.cfg; 
  grep -oP 'email_recipients=\K.*' webcheck-$category.cfg
)
```

`read` reads lines from stdin into variables. `-d ''` turns off whitespace splitting, except for newlines. `-r` disables `\` escapes.

`cmdA < <(cmdB)` works similarly to cmdB | cmdA, except in the former cmdA is run in ~this~ shell, instead of a subshell, which is required for read to work as expected.

Comment: Can you some explanation on the different parts of the line?

Comment: This is true, but how is it relevant to the question asked where the objective is to read from a file with `var=value`?